# How to add multiple numbers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

So, I'm a beginner and I'm learning C++.

I'm trying to create a program that that adds multiple numbers im trying to use loops. I've tried everything, but the calculator gives me wrong answers or just does not work.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float num1;
    float num2;
    char sign;
    float result = 0;

    cout << "press 1 to calculate averages or press 2 to use simple" << endl;
    cin >> sign;
    if (sign == '2')
    {

        goto start;
    }

start:
    cout << "Calculator" << endl;



    cout << "enter number" << endl;

    cin >> num1;

    cout << "* to multiply, / to divide, + to add and - to subtract" << endl;

    cin >> sign;


    cout << "enter another number" << endl;

    cin >> num2;


    do 
    { 
    cout << "press = to find result or enter another number" << endl;
    cin >> sign ||num2;
        result = num1 += num2;

    }

    while (sign != '=');

    cout << "the result is: " << result << endl;
    system ("pause");



}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Or has someone any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: You have a typo: `cin >> sign ||num2;` should be `cin >> sign >> num2;`, but then you have to clarify how you want to proceed. If the user wants to sum many numbers he has to write them and terminate them with an `=`, so it means the input can be either a number or a character. This complicates things, as you must treat the input as a generic string and in case convert it to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Put 4+2+2= into it. Expected result: 8. Actual result: 10. What happens?

```
cout << "enter number" << endl;
cin >> num1;
```

num1 = 4

```
cout << "* to multiply, / to divide, + to add and - to subtract" << endl;
cin >> sign;
```

sign = '+'

```
cout << "enter another number" << endl;
cin >> num2;
```

num2 = 2

```
do 
{ 

cout << "press = to find result or enter another number" << endl;
cin >> sign ||num2;
```

throw away the first '+', sign = second '+', num2 stays as 2

```
result = num1 += num2;
```

num1 = 4 + 2, num1 = 6, result = 6

```
cout << "press = to find result or enter another number" << endl;
cin >> sign ||num2;
```

sign = final 2, num2 = original 2

```
    result = num1 += num2;
```

num1 is 6 from before, num1 = 6 + 2 = 8, result = 8

```
cout << "press = to find result or enter another number" << endl;
cin >> sign ||num2;
```

sign = final '=', num2 = original 2

```
    result = num1 += num2;
```

num1 is 8 from before, num1 = 8 + 2 = 10, result = 10

```
}
while (sign != '=');   // get past here 
cout << "the result is: " << result << endl;
```

print 10

So, you're doing lots of things which aren't pulling together into a coherent calculator at all.

Answer (score 0):

First (Syntax)

```
cin >> sign ||num2;
```

this wont work as you expected. Read more about bitwise operator and how it works.

Second (logic)

if you want the user to continue entering value before you produce output you need to do it in a different logic (something like this).

```
// after you have the operator choice and the first two values
do{
 switch sign{
  // perform the operation and store the value in result
 result = num1 + num2; // for addition
 }
 // ask if the user wants to continue entering numbers
 if (yes){ // swap values as follows
   num1 = result;
   cin >> num2; 
   continue = true;
 }
 else
  continue = false;
}while(continue);
```

but this wont allow you to keep changing the operator whenever the user expects.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a loop by continuing to prompt the user to enter an equation until they enter some sentinel value, for example: 0*0

The code that you're using now doesn't really do the calculations, while you store the operator they want to use into the "sign" variable you don't perform the appropriate calculations with the variables you've collected.

You could use conditionals (i.e. if (sign == '*') then multiply) but a switch statement would probably be easier in this case. I've created a simple calculator using the same variables and showing how you can use a switch statement in this case, switching on the variable "sign" to determine when to do which calculation.

The loop uses the sentinel value 0*0, so when the user enters that equation the program quits and outputs the message "Goodbye!". You can incorporate parts of this code into your project, you'll still need to add in the beginning part (press 1 to calculate averages or 2 to do calculations) but this calculator bit should get you started.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main () {

    float num1, num2;
    char sign;
    float result;

    //you can set a sentinal value of "0/0" to implement a do/while loop

    do {

        cout << "Enter an equation (+,-,/,*) or '0*0' to exit: ";
        cin >> num1 >> sign >> num2;

        //stores the first number into num1, the operator into sign, and the second number into num2

        //if the user enters the sentinal value, break out of the loop

        if (num1 == 0 && sign == '*' && num2 == 0)
            break;  


        //use a switch statement to do the right equation depending on the operator

        switch (sign) {
            case '+':
                result = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case '-':
                result = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case '*':
                result = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case '/':
                result = num1 / num2;

        }



        //output the result
        cout << "Result = " << result << endl;

    } while (num1 != 0 && sign != '/' && num2 != 0);

    cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;

}
```